# sharepoint document library view to show actual images uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-designer, document-library, jquery

Scenario : Sharepoint 2010 document library.

Users click on 'add new document' and upload a picture (They always upload pictures or images only).

The default view shows the 'Type' and the filename.

Is there a way to show the actual image that was uploaded. I am not looking for thumbnail of the image here.

Please suggest if something is possible out-of-box. If not, through customization.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the actual image and not a thumbnail. Do you want to see the entire large image uploaded? Using an image library will give you a thumbnail look at all images.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an image library instead of a document library. If that is not possible somehow you will have to edit the library using SharePoint designer and create a custom view. To see how this view should be configured you can look at the image library view that displays the images.

Comment: nldev suggestion is correct. Picture library can make the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Image libraries don't work with custom master pages.  It's a SharePoint defect.